# Rails - instance variable does not preserve value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a `Portfolio` `scaffold`. From the `update` method of the `controller`, I am calling the `show` `view`. However, a variable (`@weights`) that I am instantiating in the `controller` does not preserve its value.

Controller:

```
@weights = @portfolio.compute_weights
pp "in the controller, the weights are #{@weights}"
format.html { redirect_to @portfolio, notice: 'Portfolio was successfully updated.' }
format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @portfolio }
```

View

```
<% pp "in the view, the weights are #{@weights}"%>
```

The output is

```
"in the controller, the weights are {\"Bitcoin\"=>1.0, \"Litecoin\"=>0.0}"
"in the view, the weights are "
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Put this in your view file `<%= debug @weights%>` and let me know what you are getting

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting to a different controller when in format.html block.

All the initialized variables are lost, if we redirect to another controller method.

Comment: Is there any way of storing a hash for every record?

Comment: can you ask it as a different question??

Answer (score 0):

Change `pp` to `=` and try like this,

```
<%= "in the view, the weights are #{@weights}"%>
```